# QuickLook not displaying pdf only gray screen with file name as title

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, quicklook

I have added QuickLook in my app to show docs, pdf etc from Document Directory, It is working fine in simulator but in iPad it's only showing file name as title and gray screen instead of pdf page, don't know whats wrong in there here is the code

```
docUrlLocal = jobDocument.docFileLocal
docUrlLocal = docUrlLocal.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "") 
/* Simulator path /Users/varunnaharia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/86CE9E4C-7D50-4831-934C-442A7558024C/data/Containers/Data/Application/86E66141-4F69-4347-81B5-415F805884C1/Documents/33fe5731-129a-4b8e-aa67-c3e840a69677.pdf 
   iPad Path     /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/743CEA41-89F4-4EEF-84E5-FCECA1FCB038/Documents/33fe5731-129a-4b8e-aa67-c3e840a69677.pdf
*/
let ql = QLPreviewController()
ql.dataSource  = self
parentVC.present(ql, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And code to download and save doc

```
let fileName = (self.docURL as NSString).lastPathComponent
                    let fullFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: 
FileManager.documentsDir()).appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
                    let destination = 
DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
                    Alamofire.download(
                        self.docURL,
                        method: .get,
                        parameters: nil,
                        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                        headers: nil,
                        to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                            //progress closure

                        }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                            //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                            //result closure
                            self.jobDocument.docFileLocal = fullFilePath.absoluteString
                            self.parentVC.tblView.reloadData()
                            self.btnOpen.isHidden = true
                        })
```

Comment: Which URL do you give Quick Look in your datasource?
Note: your code to strip file:// is fishy. If you want to access the path, use either url.path or url.fileSystemRepresentation depending on the API you want to use with it.

Comment: Simulator path is working but the device is not working it doesn't matter if there is file:// there or not, actually in device pdf is not visible but if I share that pdf to any other app it's showing content.

Comment: have u found any fix for this?

Comment: @Aleksandr no there was some bug or something with os and replaced with webview to open file

Answer (score 0):

Idk, if that's really ur problem, I fixed it like this:

```
    let filename          = name.fileName().replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: " ")
    let fileExtension     = name.fileExtension()
    let fixedFileTypeName = filename + fileExtension
```

So the problem was dots in the file name (url)

Comment: probably, not, coz I don't see dots in ur filename, but I hope, it will help somebody with the similar problem.